# JewleryBox OSX 10.6.8

Tags: ruby, rvm

Where to find JewleryBox (ruby rvm gui) that works on 10.6.8?

Current version on web site http://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com/ claims that it works for 10.6.8 but when started notes that it requires OSX 10.7.

Comment: Not to be a naysayer, but why not just learn to use it form the command line? It's much easier and more powerful. Just give it a try.

Comment: This isn't a question for Stack Overflow, but for the support for Jewelrybox. Their [FAQ](http://jewelrybox.unfiniti.com/#!faq) talks about 10.6 support being dropped "soon", hinting it would be after Mountain Lion shipped, which has happened. And, as @Linuxios says, try learning to use RVM from the command-line.

Comment: Hoped that someone already had experience with this tool. 
I have recently installed rails so I suspect rails installer installed JewleryBox too (noticed it later). I have tried it, and liked interactivity and information it gives compared to cl tools that are a bit confusing. Since it was crashing, I sought update, and after update, it would not work anymore, until eventually reported an error about OSX version. Thanks for hints, it seems that I have to give up on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.6 support has been dropped to pave the way for utilizing better APIs in newer versions of OS X. I can give you a copy of the last version that runs on 10.6, v1.3. Keep in mind though that you'll be unable to upgrade RVM past about 1.16 or so because changes were introduced in RVM that broke JewelryBox. Those fixes were added in v1.4, which is only for 10.7 or newer.

Ping me @remear to remind me as I'll need to dig up the old version and place it in a location from which you can download it.

Comment: my rvm is already rvm 1.17.2 (stable). Thus I believe that I can close this q. Thank you!

Comment: I meant anything newer than 1.16 or so (can't remember the exact version) won't work at all. You can always upgrade RVM from the command line and even JewelryBox itself gets the latest stable version during updates so it would upgrade RVM past what it's capable of running on. Therefore, you'll have to install an old version of RVM and never upgrade it or JewelryBox. I'd recommend upgrading OS X if you can, but I'll do my best to help. 10.6 support was mainly dropped because it takes a lot of time to code in 10.6 conditionals and we just don't have time to do that with the donations received.

Comment: Fully understandable, Remear. There's no harm. Now I understand why it was not working for me even in original installation that looked like working. Things go on. 
Possibly at some stage I may get a new machine and a new OS, then I will come back to it.